# Reload Audio Cache without Refreshing Page JS/NODE.JS

Tags: java, html, node.js, audio

i have a node.js express server and js-html-css web trying to get audio from node.js server and stream it on web. I am able to do that with one issue. When audio reloaded with new request html audio source should be reloaded. I have to refresh to page to listen new voice . How can i reset cache and reload whenever button clicked.

//This is audio tag

```
<audio controls="controls">
        <source src="http://localhost:8080/stream" type="audio/ogg" preload="metadata" />
        <source src="http://localhost:8080/stream" type="audio/mpeg" preload="metadata" />
       
    </audio>
```

//This is js file

```
window.onload=function(){
  var mb = document.getElementById('firstbutton');
  mb.addEventListener('click',triggerFUN)

}

async function triggerFUN(){
  const input =  document.getElementById("uniqueID");
const value = input ? input.value : '';
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = value
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var yourUrl = "http://localhost:8080/index"
xhr.open("POST", yourUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: value
}));
console.log(value)


}
```

//and this is stream endpoint

```
app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  const file = __dirname + '/output.mp3';
    fs.exists(file, (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            const rstream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            rstream.pipe(res);
        } else {
            res.send('Error - 404');
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue.